# i am unable to display data from database from $_GET method in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php  if(isset($_GET['edit'])){?>
<section class="content">
<?php  
    $id=$_GET['edit'];
    $this->load->model('databasemodel');
    $data1['hello_1']=$this->databasemodel->get_data_where($id);
    foreach ($hello_1 as $test) {
    $test->title;
    }
$this->load->view('admin/headingsform'); ?>
</section>
<?php  } ?>
```

and am getting error
Message: Undefined variable: hello_1

Comment: First you need to sanatise your input. At the very least $id=$_GET['edit'] needs to be $id=intval($_GET['edit']) then your result instead of $data1['hello_1'] just needs to be $hello_1

Comment: how did you do? Have you found a solution?

Comment: thanx i got the solution

Comment: Would you mind sharing it? So other users with a similar problem can find help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have never given `$hello_1` any value in your code.

Get your values by calling codeigniters `get()` function:

`$values = $this->input->get();` to sanatize your input.

After retrieving your values to `$data1['hello_1']` you need to use them like that, so your loop will be:
`foreach ($data1['hello_1'] as $test)`

meaning, your complete code will look something like this:

```
<?php  
     $get_values = $this->input->get();
     if(isset($get_values['edit'])){
?>
<section class="content">
<?php  
    $this->load->model('databasemodel');
    $data1['hello_1']=$this->databasemodel->get_data_where($get_values['edit']);
    foreach ($data1['hello_1'] as $test) { //this is the important bit
        $test->title;
    }
    $this->load->view('admin/headingsform'); ?>
</section>
<?php  } ?>
```